# How to replace all same charter/string in text with different outcomes?

Tags: javascript, regex

For example let's say I want to attach the index number of each 's' in a string to the 's's.

```js
var str = "This is a simple string to test regex.";
    var rm = str.match(/s/g);
    for (let i = 0;i < rm.length ;i++) {
        str = str.replace(rm[i],rm[i]+i);
    }
    console.log(str);
```

Output: This43210 is a simple string to test regex.
Expected output: This0 is1 a s2imple s3tring to tes4t regex.

Comment: index of  what? index of the string, or the number of `s`?

Comment: Index of the current `s`.

Comment: [replace method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Using_an_inline_function_that_modifies_the_matched_characters) can also take a function as an argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest, using `replace()`:

```js
let i = 0,
    str = "This is a simple string to test regex.",
  // result holds the resulting string after modification
  // by String.prototype.replace(); here we use the
  // anonymous callback function, with Arrow function
  // syntax, and return the match (the 's' character)
  // along with the index of that found character:
  result = str.replace(/s/g, (match) => {
    return match + i++;
  });
  console.log(result);
```

Corrected the code with the suggestion — in comments — from [Ezra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53051018/how-to-replace-all-same-charter-string-in-text-with-different-outcomes/53051309?noredirect=1#comment93002564_53051309).

References:

- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- "[Regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)," from MDN.
- [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Comment: If you set `i = 0` first then you can alter the return line above to get the question's expected output: `return match + i++`

Comment: Your code output is `This 3 is6 a s10imple s17tring to tes29t regex.` I have already reached this kind of result.

Comment: @Ezra: thanks! I...somehow misread/misunderstood the 'index' part of the question.

Answer (score 2):

For something like this, I would personally go with the split and test method. For example:

```
var str = "This is a simple string to test regex.";
var split = str.split(""); //Split out every char
var recombinedStr = "";
var count = 0;
for(let i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
  if(split[i] == "s") {
    recombinedStr += split[i] + count;
    count++;
  } else {
    recombinedStr += split[i];
  }
}
console.log(recombinedStr);
```

A bit clunky, but works. It forgoes using regex statements though, so probably not exactly what you're looking for.